# Error MPI en C++

Tags: c++, linux, mpi

estoy empezando a aprender a usar OpenMPI para trabajar en paralelo en programas escritos en C++, tengo un código que funciona pero trabaja con arreglos y tratando de cambiar esos arreglos por usar la clase Vector para mas comodidad y aprender mas, pero me da un error en la función MPI_Recv()

Codigo:

```
    #include<mpi.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <vector>    //vector<int>

    using namespace std;


    vector<int> crearSubArreglo(vector<int> v, int inicio, int fin) {
        vector<int> subArreglo;         
        int auxiliar = 0;               

        for (int i = inicio; i < fin; ++i) {        
            subArreglo.push_back(v[inicio + i]);    
        }

        return subArreglo;      
    }


    void llenarArregloV(vector<int> &arreglo, int tamanio){
        for (int i = 0; i < tamanio; i++) {                 
            arreglo.push_back(1 + rand() % (99 - 1));   
        }
    }


    int main(){

        int comm_sz;
        int my_rank;

        int vec[100];
        vector<int> arreglo;

        int* sub_vec = NULL;
        vector<int> subArreglo;

        int n_over_p;
        int tamanio = 100;
        int promedio;

        MPI_Status status;

        MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

        n_over_p = 100/comm_sz;
        printf("Process %d calcula n_over_p = %d\n", my_rank, n_over_p);

        if (my_rank != 0) {

            vector<int> subArreglo;
            MPI_Recv(&subArreglo, subArreglo.size(), MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        } else {

            llenarArregloV(arreglo, tamanio);

            printf("Distribuyendo datos\n");
            for (int i = 1; i < comm_sz; i++) {

                subArreglo = crearSubArreglo(arreglo, i * n_over_p, (i * n_over_p) + n_over_p);
                MPI_Send(&subArreglo, subArreglo.size(), MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            }
            printf("Fin de distribución\n");


        }

        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;

    }
```

Esto da el siguiente error:

```
[fabian@alvaradonoso Tarea3]$ mpirun -np 4 exe
Process 0 calcula n_over_p = 25
Process 1 calcula n_over_p = 25
Process 3 calcula n_over_p = 25
Distribuyendo datos
[alvaradonoso:22703] *** An error occurred in MPI_Recv
[alvaradonoso:22703] *** reported by process [285278209,2]
[alvaradonoso:22703] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[alvaradonoso:22703] *** MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated
[alvaradonoso:22703] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[alvaradonoso:22703] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
Process 2 calcula n_over_p = 25
Fin de distribución
[alvaradonoso:22696] 2 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-errors.txt / mpi_errors_are_fatal
[alvaradonoso:22696] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
```

Como soy nuevo en esto la verdad no se como solucionar este error, digo que es la funcion MPI_Recv() ya que si comento la linea, al ejecutar no provoca el error. Entonces no se si es que puse mal un parámetro de la función o declare mal alguna variable que afecte.

PD: Mi sistema es Linux (Fedora).